# behave: how to organize files of this framework in not-toy project

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

I'm trying to cover project by BDD tests using behave framework, python. The problem is all BDD materials using not real, toy-examples.
My project is rather big and I got the following problems

1. In different .feature files I have same step names but their implementation must be different.
   Example: step name "Enter code and click submit button" may using at many different pages on the site.
   How solve this collisions?
2. If you have complex web pages under tests step implementation files grow rapidly. After few .feature files step file have more than 400+ strings of code. Divide step files according .feature files (1-to-1) is not a solution because some steps must be shared between .feature files and it becomes unobvious how to find specific step.
   Is it any possibilities to divide step implemetations by level (feature level, directory of few features level, project-wide level...)

Answer (score 5):

So you've got 2 problems, and I'll try to address both of them:

## Problem 1:

It's fine to have the same, word-for-word `Given`/`When`/`Then`'s across many of your feature files; how you implement them in your step definitions is what matters. There are two routes I would consider going: (1) taking advantage of behave's [step parameters](https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial03.html); (2) using the step's `context` object to designate which feature file or scenario you're running. In regards to (2), consider having a scenario set up like so:

```
Feature: Buying toys    

    @checkout_page
    Scenario: Proceed to checkout page
        Given Toys are in the shopping cart
        When I enter code and click submit button   <--- Same step
        Then the items will be checked out

    @purchase_page
    Scenario: Proceed to purchase page
        Given Toys are in the shopping cart
        When I enter code and click submit button   <--- Same step
        Then the items will be purchased
```

From here, you could use behave's `context` object to store the tag and use it in your step implementation:

In environment.py:

```
def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.current_scenario_tags = scenario.tags # This is a list
    # ... other stuff maybe
```

In step implementation:

```
@When("I enter code and click submit button")
def step_impl(context):
    # Assuming that the logic to enter the code and set up the clicking action
    # is identical in most regards, you should pull it out of the following for loop
    # and place it here. This may help shorten your step implementations.
    # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    #         HERE
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for tag in context.current_scenario_tags:
        if tag == "checkout_page":
            # Then handle the checkout_page scenario
            break
        elif tag == "purchase_page":
            # Then handle the purchase_page scenario
            break
```

<sub>*Depending on what tags you're already using, you may want to just do `break` statements rather than looping through the rest of the tags, assuming you already know the specific tags you're looking for.</sub>

This doesn't help your problem of having step implementations that are 400 lines long, but as the saying goes, "you can't have your cake and eat it too".

## Problem 2:

This was sort of addressed in the above, but here's a couple of things about behave and how it searches for feature files and step files, from the documentation:

> behave works with three types of files:
>
> 1. feature files written by your Business Analyst / Sponsor / whoever with your behaviour scenarios in it, and
> 2. a “steps” directory with Python step implementations for the scenarios.
> 3. optionally some environmental controls (code to run before and after steps, scenarios, features or the whole
>      shooting match).

So a `feature/` directory is required, as is a `feature/steps/` subdirectory. The answer is no, behave doesn't allow for you to create categorical folders or subdirectories within the `feature/steps/` directory. Keep in mind that when looking for the step implementation associated with a step within a feature file, behave searches all the Python files within the `feature/steps/` directory, but not recursively into the directory's subdirectories. Having a good naming convention could definitely go a long way here!